# Cannot connect to endpoint dynamo db windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, localhost, amazon-dynamodb

I've been following this tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) on how to set up a downloadable DynamoDB on my computer, but have been coming across an issue when I try to connect to a local host.

I have checked my host file and everything seems to be ok...

I am using Windows 10 cmd and these are the outputs on my command line:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\dynamodb_local_latest>java - 
D"java.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib" -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       false
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *


C:\Users\Desktop\dynamodb_local_latest>aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint- 
url http://localhost:8000

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"

C:\Users\Desktop\dynamodb_local_latest>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You must run 'aws configure' and set the required parameters (even if you're only using a local dynamo db emulator, just ignore the access/secret keys)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to running `aws configure` as mentioned in @J.S.'s answer, you will need to ensure Dynamo DB is running.  I recently had this error, where the service had shut down and I didn't realize it.  If this is your case, make sure to restart it by going to the folder it is installed in and running `java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb &`